# Build Eigen in Xcode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, clang, eigen

I have been trying integrate Eigen Library into iPhone project. I having a problem of using vectorisation.
I have to declare

```
#ifndef EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE
#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE
#endif
```

before using Eigen classes.

And I constantly get error from PacketMath.h. Telling me no matching functions.

Is there anyone can help me with this?